# & What is the story behind the Ampersand?

Tags: ampersand

Can someone explain the origin of this symbol, and deconstruct the name "ampersand"? I vaguely recall my mother's saying she learned her alphabet (early 1920s) with this symbol being the "27th letter".

Comment: http://blog.dictionary.com/ampersand/

Comment: Ms Google answers simple questions like this very easily. She can refer you to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand), for example.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/200677/58761.

Comment: As we already have a very similar question which is closed as General Reference, I guess this must be too. But the derivation of the symbol's name *ampersand* doesn't appear there.

Answer (score 3):

The origin of the name is the modified phrase ***and per se and*** (meaning *the "&" character by itself is "and"*).

The symbol comes from the Latin word *et* (meaning *and*), according to [this link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ampersand&searchmode=none).

Answer (score 0):

It's simply an abbreviation developed by scribes for the Latin word *et*.

Writing very common words (especially in medieval manuscripts where sentences were commonly connected by *and*) was tedious, and eventually shortcuts (apostrophes for missing letters, the ampersand, etc.) developed.

> Drawing on earlier works by Paul Standard and Frederick Goudy, [Jan] Tschichold collected hundreds of ampersands to chronicle the character’s evolution from 1st century Pompeiian graffiti, through medieval manuscripts, and finally to 19th century printed forms. - [*Shady Characters The secret life of punctuation*](http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-2-of-2/)

Can you see the *et* in the following?

[image])

The first is from graffiti in Pompeii (so first c. AD). The seventh is from the Book of Kells (7 c.),  and #13 is an 8th century Merovigian ampersand, already recognisable as the modern ampersand form.

> The first recorded ampersand—a rudimentary ligature of the letters “E” and “T” from the Latin word et, meaning “and”— was scratched onto a Pompeian wall by an anonymous graffiti artist around the first century A.D. ... In time, the ampersand became a ubiquitous symbol: by the nineteenth century it was taught to schoolchildren as a twenty-seventh letter of the alphabet. Before that, however, it spent an entire millennium in competition with a rival mark. The “Tironian et” (⁊), had the twofold advantage of a head start and an impeccable pedigree.